# How to generate different types of QR-Code In Angular 5 (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular5, qr-code

```js
import {Component, Inject, Input, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare let QRCode: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-qrcode',
  templateUrl: './qrcode.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./qrcode.component.scss']
})
export class QrcodeComponent implements OnInit {
  elementType : 'url' | 'canvas' | 'img' = 'url';
  value:any; 
  constructor() 
  {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.value  = 'WWW.Google.com';
  }

}
```

```html
<ngx-qrcode [qrc-element-type]="elementType " [qrc-value] = "value">
  </ngx-qrcode>
```

I need to generate qr-code, i have done that, but want to change the TYPE of qr-code that means. when we scan the qr-code Contact details will automatically add Contact details , "Get Direction" for Map Qr-Code,E-Mail Type will directed to our Mail box and PDF Download functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change the type of the content, let's say you want to encode a value which contains an email or another one with an url, that's not that type meant here. Only the user's device decides whether or how the payload (value) of the qrcode is processed.

Type here means "rendered as canvas-tag" or "rendered as img-Tag".

**Longer part:**

If you look at the source of the lib, elementType is passed to a switch-statement, which itself defaults (for url & img) to img. As there is not so much documentation about the elementType on the packages site itself, I had a look at the samples on the underlying package called [qrcode](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode)

From the qrcode docs:
toCanvas (canvas) = Draws qr code symbol to canvas.
toDataURL (img, url) = Returns a string representation of the QR Code.
Currently only works for SVG.

So, without digging too deep into the lib itself, it should be as simple as writing to get your encoded email as a qrcode, rendered in an image-tag.

```
<ngx-qrcode [qrc-element-type]="img" [qrc-value]="mailto:test@example.com"></ngx-qrcode>
```

As the qrc-element-type defaults to "toDataURL", you might omit it (haven't tested this) or need some additonal ' around your values.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of another QR-Code package called [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode), which works for Angular4,5 and 6.

I made a working demo app for angular5/6 available here:
https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode-sample-app